# ms4: free() invalid pointer 0xb74e74e0 ***

Tags: c++

When I try and compile my code, I get

> ***glibc detected *** ms4: free() invalid pointer 0xb74e74e0 ***

error. I am not sure what this error means or where it is happening it. Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

NonPerishable.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "NonPerishable.h"
#include "ErrorMessage.h"

namespace sict {

using namespace std;

void NonPerishable::name(const char* cName) {

    if (m_name != nullptr) {

        delete[] m_name;

    }

    if (cName != nullptr) {

        m_name = nullptr;
        m_name = new char[strlen(cName) + 1];
        strcpy(m_name, cName);

    }
}

const char* NonPerishable::name() const {

    return m_name;

}

double NonPerishable::cost() const {

    double final = m_price;

    if (m_taxable) {

        final += (m_price * taxRate);

    }

    return final;

}

void NonPerishable::message(const char* msg) {

    this->m_error.message(msg);

}

bool sict::NonPerishable::isClear() const {

    return m_error.isClear();

}

NonPerishable::NonPerishable(const char type) {

    m_prodType = type;
    strcpy(m_sku, "");
    m_name = nullptr;
    strcpy(m_unit, "");
    m_quantity = 0;
    m_amountNeeded = 0;
    m_price = 0.0;
    m_taxable = true;
    m_error.clear();

}

NonPerishable::NonPerishable(const char* sku, const char* name, const char* unit, int quantity, bool taxable, double price, int needed) {

    m_prodType = 'N';
    strcpy(m_sku, sku);
    m_name = nullptr;
    strcpy(m_unit, unit);
    m_quantity = quantity;
    m_amountNeeded = needed;
    m_price = price;
    m_taxable = taxable;
    m_error.clear();
    this->name(name);

}

NonPerishable::NonPerishable(const NonPerishable& obj) {

    m_prodType = 'N';
    strcpy(m_sku, obj.m_sku);
    strcpy(m_unit, obj.m_unit);
    m_quantity = obj.m_quantity;
    m_amountNeeded = obj.m_amountNeeded;
    m_price = obj.m_price;
    m_taxable = obj.m_taxable;
    this->name(obj.m_name);

}

NonPerishable& NonPerishable::operator=(const NonPerishable& obj) {

    m_prodType = 'N';
    strcpy(m_sku, obj.m_sku);
    strcpy(m_unit, obj.m_unit);
    m_quantity = obj.m_quantity;
    m_amountNeeded = obj.m_amountNeeded;
    m_price = obj.m_price;
    m_taxable = obj.m_taxable;
    this->name(obj.m_name);

    /*if (!obj.m_error.isClear()) {

        m_error.message(obj.m_error.message());

    }*/

    return *this;

}

NonPerishable::~NonPerishable() {

    if (m_name != nullptr) {

        delete[] m_name;

    }
}

std::fstream& NonPerishable::store(std::fstream& file, bool newLine) const {

    if (!isEmpty()) {

        file << m_prodType << "," << m_sku << "," << m_name << "," << m_unit << "," << m_quantity << "," << m_amountNeeded << "," << m_price << "," << m_taxable << "," << m_error.message();

        if (newLine) {

            file << endl;

        }
    }

    return file;

}

std::fstream& NonPerishable::load(std::fstream& file) {

    char empty;

    file >> m_prodType >> empty >> m_sku >> empty >> m_name >> empty >> m_unit >> empty >> m_quantity >> empty >> m_amountNeeded >> empty >> m_price >> empty >> m_taxable;

    return file;

}

std::ostream& NonPerishable::write(std::ostream& os, bool linear) const {

    if (!isEmpty()) {

        if (linear) {

            os << setw(max_sku_length) << m_sku << "|" << setw(20) << m_name << "|" << setw(7) << m_price << "|" << setw(4) << m_quantity << "|" << setw(10) << m_unit << "|" << setw(4) << m_amountNeeded;

        }

        else {

            os << "Sku: " << m_sku << endl
                << "Name: " << m_name << endl
                << "Price: " << m_price << endl;

            if (m_taxable) {

                os << "Price after tax: " << total_cost() << endl;

            }

            else {

                os << "N/A" << endl;

            }

            os << "Quantity on Hand: " << m_quantity << endl
                << "Quantity Needed: " << m_amountNeeded << endl;

        }
    }

    return os;

}

std::istream& NonPerishable::read(std::istream& is) {

    char tempChar;
    bool valid = false;
    double tempNum;
    int tempInt;

    cout << "Sku: ";
    is >> m_sku;
    cout << "Name: ";
    is >> m_name;
    cout << "Unit: ";
    is >> m_unit;
    cout << "Taxed? (y/n): ";
    is >> tempChar;

    if (tempChar == 'y' || tempChar == 'Y') {

        m_taxable = true;
        valid = true;

    }

    if (tempChar == 'n' || tempChar == 'N') {

        m_taxable = false;
        valid = true;

    }

    if (!valid) {

        is.istream::setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        m_error.message("Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable");

    }

    cout << "Price: ";
    is >> tempNum;

    if (tempNum >= 0) {

        m_price = tempNum;

    }

    if (is.std::ios::fail()) {

        m_error.message("Invalid Price Entry");

    }

    cout << "Quantity on Hand: ";
    is >> tempInt;

    if (tempInt >= 0) {

        m_quantity = tempInt;

    }

    if (is.std::ios::fail()) {

        m_error.message("Invalid Quantity Entry");

    }

    cout << "Quantity Needed: ";
    is >> tempInt;

    if (tempInt >= 0) {

        m_amountNeeded = tempInt;

    }

    if (is.std::ios::fail()) {

        m_error.message("Invalid Quantity Needed Entry");

    }

    return is;

}

bool NonPerishable::operator==(const char* sku) const {

    if (strcmp(sku, this->m_sku) == 0) {

        return true;

    }
    else {

        return false;

    }
}

double NonPerishable::total_cost() const {

    double total = m_price * m_quantity;

    if (m_taxable) {

        total += ((m_price * m_quantity) * taxRate);

    }

    return total;

}

void NonPerishable::quantity(int amount) {

    m_quantity = amount;

}

bool NonPerishable::isEmpty() const {

    if (m_sku[0] == '\0' && m_name == nullptr && m_unit[0] == '\0' && m_quantity == 0 && m_amountNeeded == 0 && m_price == 0 && m_taxable == true) {

        return true;

    }
    else {

        return false;

    }
}

int NonPerishable::qtyNeeded() const {

    return m_amountNeeded;

}

int sict::NonPerishable::quantity() const {

    return m_quantity;

}

bool NonPerishable::operator>(const char* sku) const {

    if (m_sku > sku) {

        return true;

    }
    else {

        return false;

    }
}

int NonPerishable::operator+=(int units) {

    if (units > 0) {

        m_quantity += units;
        m_amountNeeded -= units;

    }

    return m_quantity;

}

bool NonPerishable::operator>(const Product& obj) const {

    if (m_name > obj.name()) {

        return true;

    }
    else {

        return false;

    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Product& obj) {

    obj.write(os, true);

    return os;

}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Product& obj) {

    obj.read(is);

    return is;

}

double operator+=(double& cost, const Product& obj) {

    return (cost + obj.total_cost());

}

Product* CreateProduct() {

    Product* temp = nullptr;
    temp = new NonPerishable;

    return temp;

    }
}
```

NonPerishable.h

```
#ifndef SICT_NONPERISHABLE_H
#define SICT_NONPERISHABLE_H

#include "Product.h"
#include "ErrorMessage.h"

namespace sict {

const int max_sku_length = 7;
const int max_unit_length = 10;
const int max_name_length = 75;
const double taxRate = 0.13;

class NonPerishable : public Product {

    char m_prodType;
    char m_sku[max_sku_length];
    char* m_name;
    char m_unit[max_unit_length];
    int m_quantity;
    int m_amountNeeded;
    double m_price;
    bool m_taxable;
    ErrorMessage m_error;

protected:

    void name(const char* name);
    const char* name() const;
    double cost() const;
    void message(const char* msg);
    bool isClear() const;

public:

    NonPerishable(const char type = '\0');
    NonPerishable(const char* sku, const char* name, const char* unit, int quantity = 0, bool taxable = true, double price = 0, int needed = 0);
    NonPerishable(const NonPerishable& obj);
    NonPerishable& operator=(const NonPerishable& obj);
    ~NonPerishable();

    std::fstream& store(std::fstream& file, bool newLine = true) const;
    std::fstream& load(std::fstream& file);
    std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, bool linear) const;
    std::istream& read(std::istream& is);

    bool operator==(const char* sku) const;
    double total_cost() const;
    void quantity(int amount);
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int qtyNeeded() const;
    int quantity() const;
    bool operator>(const char* sku) const;
    int operator+=(int units);
    bool operator>(const Product& obj) const;

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Product& obj);
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Product& obj);
double operator +=(double& cost, const Product& obj);
Product* CreateProduct();

}
#endif
```

I have tried looking online for a solution but haven't found any. I hope someone more experienced can help.

Comment: You tried deallocating an invalid chunk of memory.

Comment: thank you for explaining chris, how do i fix this?

Comment: Use a debugger or memory tools like valgrind or a sanitizer to figure out where the crash is happening and do some investigation into how that pointer got an invalid value. The smaller the program that reproduces the problem, the easier it is to do that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the copy constructor

```
NonPerishable::NonPerishable(const NonPerishable& obj) {

    m_prodType = 'N';
    strcpy(m_sku, obj.m_sku);
    strcpy(m_unit, obj.m_unit);
    m_quantity = obj.m_quantity;
    m_amountNeeded = obj.m_amountNeeded;
    m_price = obj.m_price;
    m_taxable = obj.m_taxable;
    this->name(obj.m_name);

}
```

you never initialize `m_name`. That might cause the `this->name(obj.m_name);` call to delete an uninitialized pointer.

Also in the `name` function

```
void NonPerishable::name(const char* cName) {

    if (m_name != nullptr) {

        delete[] m_name;

    }

    if (cName != nullptr) {

        m_name = nullptr;
        m_name = new char[strlen(cName) + 1];
        strcpy(m_name, cName);

    }
}
```

if `cName` happens to be a `nullptr`, you will delete `m_name` but not give it a new value. That will cause a double delete later, like in the destructor.

---

All of this could be avoided by using `std::string` instead of char pointers.

Comment: Thank you. What I took from what you said was to add m_name = nullptr; to the copy constructor and to before the (cName != nullptr)
edit: that fixed the problem, thank you.